# Basis and linear independence with the 0 intersection

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

We are asked to show that the set {u1, w1, w2, w3 }is linearly independent, given that V is a vector space and U and W are subspaces of V such that U intersection W is {0}and we suppose that {u1} is a basis of U and {w1,w2, w3} is a basis for W.
I know that since the intersection of the two subpaces W and U is the 0 vector, we can say that any non-zero vector in U is linearly independent from any non-zero vector in W  because the vectors in U do not belong to the span of W and so are the vetors of W. Therefore we can conclude that u1, w1, w2, w3 are linearly independent. Am I right?

Comment: You're right. Just to put some order, I think the easiest way is just saying that $\{w_1,w_2,w_3\}$ is LI and spans $W$, and since $u_1\in U$ and $u_1 \neq 0$, then $u_1\notin W=\langle w_1,w_2,w_3\rangle$ and so $\{w_1,w_2,w_3,u_1\}$ is also LI.

Comment: oh okay,so I just need to be more specific

Comment: @AlejandroNasifSalum That's correct, but does not scale when $\dim U=2$, for instance.

Comment: @egreg Sure. Maybe it's not casual that $\dim U=1$ in this case. Perhaps there are more exercises where they're expected to use a more general argument, like the one you suggest in your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that argument is insufficient.

Consider a linear combination
$$
\alpha_1u_1+\beta_1w_1+\beta_2w_2+\beta_3w_3=0
$$
Your task is to prove that $\alpha_1=0$, $\beta_1=0$, $\beta_2=0$ and $\beta_3=0$.

Now, by assumption,
$$
\beta_1w_1+\beta_2w_2+\beta_3w_3=-\alpha_1u_1
$$
What can you say about this vector that can be written in these two ways?

> Call $x$ this vector; then, by construction, $x\in U\cap W$ and therefore $x=0$. Hence $\alpha_1=0$, because $u_1\ne0$, and $\beta_1w_1+\beta_2w_2+\beta_3w_3=0$ implies $\beta_1=\beta_2=\beta_3=0$ by linear independence of $\{w_1,w_2,w_3\}$.
> Note that this easily scales up; the same can be said if you have a basis $\{u_1,\dots,u_m\}$ of $U$, a basis $\{w_1,\dots,w_n\}$ of $W$ and $U\cap W=\{0\}$.

Comment: I don't know how this can help us at this stage; we still need to prove that all of the scalars are 0 and I don;t see how we can do that

Comment: Can you please explain more?

Comment: @DanielKamand $-\alpha_1u_1\in U$ and $\beta_1w_1+\beta_2w_2+\beta_3w_3\in W$; but that's the same vector, so…

Comment: but we don't have this vector in the intersection unless it is the zero vector,

Comment: @DanielKamand Exactly so: the *only* vector in the intersection is $0$, so $-\alpha_1u_1=0$ and $\beta_1w_1+\beta_2w_2+\beta_3w_3=0$. Now use the linear independence of $\{w_1,w_2,w_3\}$ you have by assumption and that $u_1\ne0$.

Comment: so if u is different than the zero vector this cannot happen right?

Comment: @DanielKamand You conclude that $\alpha_1=0$, don't you? This is not a proof by contradiction.

Comment: Oh okay I see !

Comment: yes I do conclude,and then they will be linearly independent